# What is the "t" letter in the output of "ls -ld /tmp"?

Tags: permissions, tmp

When running the command `ls -ld /tmp`, the output would be:

```
drwxrwxrwt 30 root root 20480 Mar 11 14:17 /tmp
```

So I have two main questions:

- What is the letter `t` after the permissions?
- As far as I know `/tmp` is used to create temporary files related to
  different users in the system, so how come it has permission `rwxrwxrwx` (777)?

This seems wrong for me. Please I need your help to understand what is going here.

Comment: Read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit), it's rather better than the answers here.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79395/4784

Comment: OK Why then, when I install an Update or a new rpm Package from /tmp, does the sticky bit get removed?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

#### So what is the sticky bit?

A sticky bit is a permission bit that is set on a directory that allows only the owner of the file within that directory, the owner of the directory or the root user to delete or rename the file. No other user has the needed privileges to delete the file created by some other user.

This is a security measure to avoid deletion of critical folders and their content (sub-directories and files), though other users have full permissions.

#### Why does `/tmp` have the `t` sticky bit?

The `/tmp` directory can be used by different Linux users to create temporary files. Now, what if a user deletes/renames a file created by some other user in this directory?

Well, to avoid these kind of issues, the concept of sticky bit is used. So for that a `777` is given but preserving the sticky bit is not a bad idea.

#### How can I set up the sticky bit for a directory?

I'll set a sticky bit on a directory called `test` on my Desktop.

Using symbolic notation (`t` represents the sticky bit):

```
chmod o+t ~/Desktop/test
```

or

```
chmod +t ~/Desktop/test
```

Using octal notation (`1` in the first position represents the sticky bit):

```
chmod 1757 ~/Desktop/test
```

Now let us test the results:

```
ls -li ~/Desktop/test

1551793 drwxrwxrwt 45 hadi hadi 20485 Mar 11 14:35 ~/Desktop/test
```

To delete/Remove a sticky bit

```
chmod o-t ~/Desktop/test
```

Now let us test the results:

```
ls -li ~/Desktop/test

1551793 drwxrwxrwx 45 hadi hadi 20485 Mar 11 14:35 ~/Desktop/test
```

Source: [“What is a sticky Bit and how to set it in Linux?” at The Linux Juggernaut](http://www.linuxnix.com/2012/01/sticky-bit-set-linux.html)

Comment: This usage of the sticky bit only applies to directories, not files.  In the distant past, its meaning on executable files was to save the program's text segment to swap rather than discarding it so that running it again would be faster, but these days it has no meaning on regular files.

Comment: what was a program's text segment and how would keeping it make it faster?

Comment: @BluePython The 'text' segment of an executable file is the part that includes all the machine code: the actual executable bit. Common other segments are 'data' for static data and 'bss' for data that's all zero (and thus doesn't need to be stored in the executable).

Comment: is there any difference between 't' and 'T' for directory permission ??@psusi

Comment: @Afshin :  Because the `t` hides the `x` indicating whether all users can execute the file/directory, we need some other way of indicating this.  The usual thing is that everybody can execute it, in which case you get a normal `t` (instead of an `x`).  But if not, then you get an uppercase `T` (instead of a `-`).  Source: Wikipedia.

Answer (score 28):

> A Sticky bit is a permission bit that is set on a file or a directory that lets only the owner of the file/directory or the root user to delete or rename the file. No other user is given privileges to delete the file created by some other user.

Sometime it happens that you need Linux directory that can be used by all the users of the Linux system for creating files. Users can create, delete or rename files according to their convenience in this directory.

> Now, what if an user accidentally or deliberately deletes (or rename) a file created by some other user in this directory?
>
> Well, to avoid these kind of issues, the concept of sticky bit is used. Since **/tmp** is used for this purpose. So to avoid the above scenario, **/tmp** use  sticky bit.

For example:

```
mkdir demo
chmod 777 demo
```

I also created two file with different user in this folder having permission 777.

```
ls -ld demo
drwxrwxrwx 2 guru guru 4096 Mar 11 18:17 demo

ls -l demo
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abhi abhi    0 Mar 11 17:11 file1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 anshu anshu   0 Mar 11 18:15 file2
```

Now turn on the sticky bit on this

```
 chmod +t demo/
 ls -ld demo
 drwxrwxrwt 2 guru guru 4096 Mar 11 18:17 demo
```

Now what happens if one user(abhi) want to rename the 2nd user(anshu)

```
mv /home/guru/demo/file2  /home/guru/demo/file3
mv: cannot move '/home/guru/demo/file2' to  '/home/guru/demo/file3': Operation not   permitted
```

**The origin of the sticky bit**

On Linux, the sticky bit only has the use described above, on directories. Historically, it was used for something completely different on regular files, and this is where the name comes from.

> When a program is executed, it takes time to load the program into memory before the user can actually start using it. If a program, for example an editor is used frequently by users the the start-up time delay was an overhead back then.
>
> To improve this time delay, the sticky bit was introduced. The OS checked that if sticky bit on an executable is ON, then the text segment of the executable was kept in the swap space. This made it easy to load back the executable into RAM when the program was run again thus minimizing the time delay.

Modern systems such as Linux manage their cache of executables and other files automatically and don't need the sticky bit for that.

Source: [“Linux Sticky Bit Concept Explained with Examples” at The Geek Stuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/02/sticky-bit/)

Answer (score 2):

A stickybit is a workaround method for shared directories not to be deleted accidentally. When a directory has a stickybit then only the owner or the root can delete it even that every user can take the full other permissions.

`/tmp` is the most shared directory between processes and users and for that it contains the stickybit to ensure that no user can delete the directory, even that the permission is `777` , and it must be so to give the ability to the users and processes to use the directory without conflict in permissions.