# Move /tmp (ssd) to /home (hhd)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, tmp

I have an SSD (256gb) with two partitions, one of the with Ubuntu. I also have an HDD with `/home` and a partition for data (music, videos, etc). I would like to move `/tmp` (on the ssd) to `/home` (on the hdd). So far I have only found one answer saying that the way to do this is:

```
mv /tmp ~/tmp
ln -s ~/tmp /tmp
```

Would this actually work? Shouldn't I also change something in `/etc/fstab`?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to move the content of `/tmp` to `/home` or do you want to create a new partition on you HDD for `/tmp`. Many set ups have their `/tmp` directory entirely in main memory on a tmpfs file system by the way, since there's nothing in there that needs to survive a reboot.

Comment: The issue started when I wanted to open a file in audacity and I didn't have enough space on /root. I only have 10gbs available there. But I guess a better solution would be to move /tmp to RAM (I have 24gb of RAM).

Comment: I've just moved /tmp to RAM but /var/tmp keeps filling up. For what I read, /var/tmp should not be moved to ram. So I guess I should move it to /home (btw, I already have a partition for home at the hdd and that's where I would like to move /var/tmp

Comment: Good to know. I had `/var/tmp` symlinked to `/tmp` (luckily without problems so far). In my setup `/var` and `/home` are entirely on HDD, while the rest of `/` is on SDD.

Answer (score 0):

It would, but you would also need to do some more things. The default permissions of `/tmp` are this:

```
# stat /tmp
...
Access: (1777/drwxrwxrwt)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

Since the permissions of the link are the permissions of the target, you will have to change the permissions of `~/tmp`. At the least, it should be world-readable and -writable:

```
chmod a+rwx ~/tmp
```

The `t` bit should also be set (see [What is the "t" letter in the output of "ls -ld /tmp"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/432699/158442)):

```
chmod +t ~/tmp
```

There might be other problems. If any directory in the path for `~/tmp` doesn't have execute bit set for others, this folder will be inaccessible for most users.

I missed the obvious flaw in this:

### Any attempt to use `/tmp` before your home directory is available will fail.

This might be one place where bind mounts are better than links.