# how do I remove the chmod +t file permissions

Tags: permissions, filemanager, chmod

I was setting up a new hard drive for temporary folders and accidentally set the `chmod +t` (sticky bit) file permission. How can I remove this setting?  I have a program using it as temp folders and when it's done I can delete the files after I read them.

Answer (score 2):

Execute

```
chmod -t your_folder
```

to remove the sticky bit.

`+` means `add` and `-` means `remove`.

Read the manpage for more details: `man chmod`

Comment: so running chmod -t your_folder will make it where who ever can delete any file or subfolder in that folder correct?

Comment: No. Read the man page and the part about the sticky bit.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432699/what-is-the-t-letter-in-the-output-of-ls-ld-tmp) have a complete explain for sticky bit

Comment: excuse me. link was broken. I was edit it.