# Is it possible to implement a "name" booking system using linux file permissions

Tags: permissions, directory, chmod, perl, multi-user

I have a linux multi user server with 100+ users in /etc/passwd

I would like to allow users to "book" / "reserve" a name of their liking (in this case a subdomain, but that details doesn't matter)

I have created a directory called `/reservations` and with chmod 777.

If user johndoe does, `touch /reservations/coolsite`, he indicates that
he would like to "own" that name "coolsite"

The "mechanism" should be set up so that,

- johndoe can have a change of mind later, and `rm /reservations/coolsite` to un-book that name
- another user is not allowed to `touch /reservations/coolsite`, because johndoe asked for it first.
- if johndoe `rm` his file, another user is allow to book it.
- users can't `rm / rename / mv / etc` other folks files
- user johndoe can have multiple bookings by doing `touch /reservations/coolsite && touch /reservations/coolsite2`

Is this possible using some kind of standard linux permissions mechanism?

I would hate to resort to perl for this, my perl skills have become rusty since the day ruby came along with her wavy blonde hair ...

Comment: I see nothing here that is out of the ordinairy. Have "coolsite" created as "700" (no permissions for group and others) and only the own user + admin can do something to it. All others get a permission denied.

Comment: So manually instruct users to remember to chmod 700 after `touch` ?

Comment: joshsverns I think you can enforce that? (with `umask`). Oh good one @perlduck

Comment: Why couldn't you program it in ruby?

Answer (score 31):

What you ask for the directory `/reservations` is exactly how the standard `/tmp` directory behaves:

Every user can create files in there and only he is allowed to delete or modify them. This is achieved by the `t` bit (aka ***sticky bit***) in the permissions. No user needs special permissions or umasks then.

Thus:

```
chown root /reservations
chmod 1777 /reservations
```

is all you need. The `chown root` is only to prevent other (regular) users from fiddling around with that directory. It's not *really* needed. Read more about the sticky bit here:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit
- [What is the "t" letter in the output of "ls -ld /tmp"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/432699/504066)