# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS WordPress Failing to Save Certain Settings in Database (Occurring with Various Sites)

Tags: server, mysql, php

I'm unable to deactivate or activate plugins on a selection of my websites but not all of them. I can't spot any similarities between the sites that have the issue and the sites that don't.
I'm getting a message to say your plugin has been deactivated or activated, but if I refresh the page, no change has been made.

I'm also having problems saving settings and they're not plugin specific.
I'm trying to keep tests to WordPress core functionality, to rule out plugin issues.
For example, if I un-tick "Discourage search engines from indexing this site" and save my settings, the setting is still ticked when the page refreshes.

I'm able to create a new page, so making database changes are working in some areas for the effected sites.

The problems started around Thursday this week.

I'd installed "iThemes Security" across my sites that day, after getting locked out by "Limit Login Attempts Reloaded".
I'm aware this plugin changes file permissions, so I've reset them as follows.
Folders – 755.
Files – 644.
wp-config. php – 600.
The problem still occurs.

I'd updated a load of packages on the server, but I couldn't say what they were.

I've used "SpinupWP" to configure my server, but understandably, I'm expected to resolve server issues myself.
Their system forced me to action an update that was referred to as...
"Upgrading so that WordPress can generate PDF preview images"
I haven't a clue what that involved or if it could relate to my issues.

I've been looking at the following advice...
https://wordpress.org/support/article/common-wordpress-errors/#database-errors
Particularly Error 13 – Cannot Create/Write to File 
I'm not sure where I would expect to see the error code 13.
I've turned on `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` and also checked the error log.

The results in the error log after deactivating a plugin (I've been testing with Regenerate Thumbnails or Enable Media Replace), but it not actually getting deactivated are...

```
2020/01/25 02:59:19 [error] 14868#14868: *34160 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; wp_my_plugin has a deprecated constructor in /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/plugins/templatera-widget/index.php on line 16PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/plugins/templatera-widget/index.php on line 80PHP message: RedisException: OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'. in /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/object-cache.php:604
Stack trace:
#0 /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/object-cache.php(604): Redis->set('caterquipventil...', 's:4591546:"a:2:...')
#1 /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/object-cache.php(545): WP_Object_Cache->add_or_replace(true, 'mainwp_child_su...', 'a:2:{i:0;a:5:{s...', 'options', 0)
#2 /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/object-cache.php(36): WP_Object_Cache->add('mainwp_child_su...', 'a:2:{i:0;a:5:{s...', 'options', 0)
#3 /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-includes/option.php(105): wp_cache_add('mainwp_child_su...', 'a:2:{i:0;a:5:{s...', 'options')
#4 /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-includes/option.php(486): get_option('mainwp_child_su...')
#5 /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/plugins/mainwp-child/class/class-mainwp-helper.php(1194): add_option('mainwp_chi" while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.158.158.145, server: domain-removed.co.uk, request: "GET /wp-admin/plugins.php?action=deactivate&plugin=regenerate-thumbnails%2Fregenerate-thumbnails.php&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s&_wpnonce=bf96608e95 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-domain-removed.sock:", host: "domain-removed.co.uk", referrer: "https://domain-removed.co.uk/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s"
2020/01/25 02:59:22 [error] 14868#14868: *34162 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; wp_my_plugin has a deprecated constructor in /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/plugins/templatera-widget/index.php on line 16PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/plugins/templatera-widget/index.php on line 80PHP message: RedisException: OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'. in /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/object-cache.php:604
Stack trace:
#0 /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/object-cache.php(604): Redis->set('caterquipventil...', 's:4646454:"a:2:...')
#1 /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/object-cache.php(545): WP_Object_Cache->add_or_replace(true, 'mainwp_child_su...', 'a:2:{i:0;a:5:{s...', 'options', 0)
#2 /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/object-cache.php(36): WP_Object_Cache->add('mainwp_child_su...', 'a:2:{i:0;a:5:{s...', 'options', 0)
#3 /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-includes/option.php(105): wp_cache_add('mainwp_child_su...', 'a:2:{i:0;a:5:{s...', 'options')
#4 /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-includes/option.php(486): get_option('mainwp_child_su...')
#5 /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/plugins/mainwp-child/class/class-mainwp-helper.php(1194): add_option('mainwp_chi" while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.158.158.145, server: domain-removed.co.uk, request: "GET /wp-admin/plugins.php?deactivate=true&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s= HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-domain-removed.sock:", host: "domain-removed.co.uk", referrer: "https://domain-removed.co.uk/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s"
2020/01/25 02:59:24 [error] 14868#14868: *34168 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; wp_my_plugin has a deprecated constructor in /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/plugins/templatera-widget/index.php on line 16PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/plugins/templatera-widget/index.php on line 80" while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.158.158.145, server: domain-removed.co.uk, request: "GET /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=updraft_ajax&subaction=ping&nonce=00421e02f8&_fs_blog_admin=true HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-domain-removed.sock:", host: "domain-removed.co.uk", referrer: "https://domain-removed.co.uk/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s"
2020/01/25 02:59:25 [error] 14868#14868: *34170 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; wp_my_plugin has a deprecated constructor in /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/plugins/templatera-widget/index.php on line 16PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /sites/domain-removed.co.uk/files/wp-content/plugins/templatera-widget/index.php on line 80" while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.158.158.145, server: domain-removed.co.uk, request: "GET /wp-json/ithemes-security/v1/admin-notices?_locale=user HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-domain-removed.sock:", host: "domain-removed.co.uk", referrer: "https://domain-removed.co.uk/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s"
```

I'm not spotting anything that can help me within that and the fact that I can create new pages, suggests I can write to the database.

However, I have located `my.cnf` within `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
After looking in the files contained within a couple of include directories, I've found my tmpdir line. `tmpdir = /tmp`. The permissions are `drwxrwxrwt` which according to [this link about the letter t permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432699/what-is-the-t-letter-in-the-output-of-ls-ld-tmp) is correct.

I've checked the DB User Privileges on a site that works and one that doesn't and they are both GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES.

I've recently had to resize the disk space from 25GB to 80GB, so the possibility of my tmp directory either being out of space or having too many files in it seems realistic. I've been looking at [this link on how to resize the tmp directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199565/not-enough-space-on-tmp). I'd be interested if anyone thinks it's worth me trying this and also if there's anything I should be worried about. Things are already far from great and I don't want to make things worse, only to get feedback like "You didn't delete the tmp directory did you?".

I've tried running `mysqlcheck -r mydatabasename` as per [this article](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2368/How-to-Repair-a-MySQL-Database-Through-Linux-and-Windows-Command-Line.html).
The prompt just changed to `->` without giving any indication as to whether anything had happened or not. Settings still won't save.

I went to try the Health Check plugin, but I was unable to activate it, so I removed all plugins from the plugins directory (except Health Check) and switched to the Twenty Twenty theme. The only issue reported was that I had debug mode switched to True.

Considering I could activate and deactivate plugins when other plugins weren't in the plugins directory, I've introduced each plugin, one at a time. For each plugin, I tried to activate, deactivate and then reactivate.
This test has been carried out with the regular theme reactivated and not the Twenty Twenty theme.
Several plugins either failed to activate or needed to be removed from the folder to deactivate. Upon a second attempt, after testing all the plugins that worked first time, they problematic plugins have also worked. I now seem to be able to activate and deactivate plugins on this site.
However, I'm still unable to save settings, so there's an underlying issue that's causing intermittent problems.

There doesn't appear to be anything of use in journalctl.

I was unable to access the `/etc/log/mysql`. The permissions were `d rwx r-x ---  root    adm` I've added myself to the `root` and `adm` groups, but that didn't help, so I've also given `Others` Read and Execute access, so that I could get in. Now that I've seen the logs, I've reverted these changes. Would it have been safe to leave Read and Execute for Others?

Now that I've viewed the mysql error logs, I can see that the websites with issues have an error that includes `"Got an error reading communication packets"`. I've tried temporarily increasing my `max_allowed_packet` and `max_connections` as per [this article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/mysql-error-reading-communication-packets). Still no luck!

I'm at a loss as to what to try next. If anyone can offer some guidance, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that SpinupWP had pushed an update, which set `maxmemory 64mb` in the `redis.conf` file. After commenting this line out and restarting the redis service, all of my problems went away.